# Online Plotly doesn't show charts

Tags: plotly

I am trying to using plotly by running the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py

py.sign_in(username="username", api_key="api_key")

n = 50
x, y, z, s, ew = np.random.rand(5, n)
c, ec = np.random.rand(2, n, 4)
area_scale, width_scale = 500, 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c,
            s=np.square(s)*area_scale,
            edgecolor=ec,
            linewidth=ew*width_scale)
ax.grid()

plot_url = py.plot_mpl(fig)
```

But, I am wondering because plotly tells me that the page doesn't exists. Precisely, I got the following page as showing in this image 
[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN2Xw.png)

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is just in your example, but as a start, did you actualy use the line `py.sign_in(username="username", api_key="api_key")` with `"username"` and `"api_key"` as strings, or did you add your own `username` and `api_key`, as found from your `settings` in your plotly account?

You matplotlib fig seems to work fine, so nothing wrong there. You can try this to view the plotly plot offline:

```
from plotly.offline import enable_mpl_offline, plot_mpl

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py

n = 50
x, y, z, s, ew = np.random.rand(5, n)
c, ec = np.random.rand(2, n, 4)
area_scale, width_scale = 500, 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c,
            s=np.square(s)*area_scale,
            edgecolor=ec,
            linewidth=ew*width_scale)
ax.grid()

plot_url = plot_mpl(fig)
```

This should open the figure in your local browser. I think you can export it from there to `plot.ly`

Comment: first, thank you for your replying. I run the offline code. Unfortunately, I got the following error


    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute       
       'return_figure_from_figure_or_data'

Do you have any idea how to fix it !

Thank you

Comment: the code works as is on my system, so I'm guessing that the problem might be in your plotly installation. Has plotly been working on your system in python before this? How did you install plotly, and which system are you running on? If you have a Linux system, you can install plotly by running "sudo pip install plotly". Also see https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/ for more details on this. Then try and run one of the examples on that webpage to test your installation.

Comment: Can you share the code you used for the "Attribute error"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I copy the web page addresss and open it in another tab, I could see the graph. (Of course you should sign in using your ID and api-key value. see https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/ )

Answer (score 0):

Solution to Problem: "Hmm... It looks like this page doesn't exist."

**You've done nothing wrong,**. It's plot.ly that has a problem with the redirection to their website! https://plot.ly/~usernamet/0/ does not work.

This first example of "get started with plotly" only upload the figure to your online plotly account that you can

**Instead,** if you've created your plotly account and are logged in in your browser, **you will see your graph uploaded on this page**: https://plot.ly/organize/home

Regarding you "Attribute error" problem, do you mind sharing the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to add username and api_key to use plotly offline library. I have created tutorials about how to use plotly offline library without using username and api_key. You can access it here: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python

After creating plots, you can also export that data and plot in online account.